# How to Animate ui view off screen and stay there on app launch &not every time the view is loaded?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I have a simple animation at the beginning of my app.

It shows a UIView over the main view that is animated off screen at launch. I only want it to animate at the app launch rather than every time the main view is loaded. My problem is that using the my code I can stop the animation as required, however it reverts back to its beginning state overlaying the view on loading the main view.

To summarise, I want to animate the UIview Off the screen and make it stay there until the app is relaunched. Any advice greatly appreciated

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performAnimation:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification   object:nil];




[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

[self setDoorbottom:nil];
       [super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)alert:(id)sender {


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];

}

- (void)performAnimation:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    // Animation code.

CGRect doorbottomFrame = doorbottom.frame;
doorbottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

doorbottom.frame = doorbottomFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Air", CFSTR
                                          ("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

  }
@end
```

Comment: where do you define your `doorbottom` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own projects, I handle splash screens through an ad-hoc view controller which I instantiate in my application delegate:

```
SDSSplashViewController* splash = [[SDSSplashViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:splash.view];
```

The `SDSSplashViewController` calls the equivalent of your `performAnimation` in its `viewDidLoad`. At the end of the animation, it removes the view from its superview.
This is very clean and great for reuse.

You can instantiate the view controller (like above) in applicationDidFinishLaunching, if you want it to be executed just once, or `applicationDidBecomeActive` if you want the animation executed each time the app becomes active (which is what you do in your code).

About your current issue: I assume you define your doorbottom view in a xib file (since you don't in viewDidLoad and you do not provide loadView).

In this case, what happens is: each time the view is loaded, it is loaded as you defined it in the xib. So, if it is visible there, and overlapping the rest of your view, it will stay that way when you do no animate away. A simple workaround would be making the animatable view `hidden` in the xib, then unhide it first thing in `performAnimation`:

```
- (void)performAnimation:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

   // Animation code.

   doorbottom.hidden = NO;
   ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, thats what I was after, simple, effective

Answer (score 1):

The very first method gets called after your initial application luanch is, `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` So, call you animation inside that instead of `viewDidLoad`.

You will find this `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method inside your app delegate.

#### Lifecycle

[image]

**All credit of this picture goes to : [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)**

Comment: Sounds a great solution, how do  declare my ui view "doorbottom" in the apps delegate, how does it know about that item.  I declared it in the .h file in Delegate and placed my animation in .m under `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` However the view will no longer animate.  Obviously im missing how to communicate the delegate to the UI Image on the view

Answer (score 1):

Matt Drance and Paul Warren cover this pretty thoroughly in their *iOS Recipes* book.
Paraphrasing the relevant section:
Assuming you're using the default.png during load as a kind of splash screen, then you need to encapsulate your animation in it's own view controller, and present is as a modal view controller off your applications root view controller...

Timing is key here, the root controller's view must be in place before it presents the modal view controller
so in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you would:

- instantiate a navcontroller view containing your splashscreen animation view controller
- add that navcontroller to the window as a subview
- present the nav controller modally  -

There are details like whether the status bar is shown that need to be taken in to account... the Drance/Warren book includes source code and a much more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have suggested putting the code to trigger your launch animation in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions.

There is a potential problem with this however.

Starting with iOS 4, your application switches to the background when the user presses the home button, and then gets a switch to foreground notification when the user taps the app icon again. You can go weeks without getting another launch notification. It seems to the user like they are launching your app again, but the system doesn't think so.

Make sure that's what you want before you decide to trigger your animation in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:

You have more flexibility if you put your code in the move to foreground method (applicationWillEnterForeground). If you use that method you can create logic that decides whether to treat this as a launch or a return from the background. (e.g. save a timestamp when you enter the background, and treat a foreground notification as a launch if a certain amount of time (an hour?) has passed since you last entered the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an event to happen only once , you could create a bool property in the AppDelegate class and you set it to true when you animate the UIView in the first time. for ex:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    BOOL animated =appDelegate.animated;
    if(!animated)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performAnimation:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification   object:nil];
        appDelegate.animated =YES;
    }

     [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 }
```